Object conversion from Blender to RealityKit
I am quite new to Blender (using 4.2.1) and I am creating some models I want to use inside a RealityKit scene. In one case, I am creating a pole with a PBR material that I want to convert to .usdz format with Reality Converter. However, the preview in RC does not match the visual I have from the model in Blender.


If you notice, the top face of the pole is not rendering correctly in RC, and the inside face is showing to the front, while the back face is not being covered by the inside face.
For this output, I have baked the textures in Blender, and exported the object as .obj, then linking the texture files back in RC. I have also tried the direct export from Blender as .usd (same result) and .gltf or .glb (latter fail to load in RC with "unknown error").
The model in Blender is UV mapped correctly, with seams to divide the inner, outer, top and bottom faces.
Before I go and learn Maya, do you have any suggestions on which workflow could fix this?

This question is offtopic here but would be a good fit for https://blender.stackexchange.com/.

I had considered exactly your objection before posting here, and I made the choice based on the relevance of the topic. My question is about a workflow process to get a working model from Blender to RealityKit, which I see many developers struggling with, and not about the model design itself, so, in my view, it is definitely more appropriate here.

Typical questions here include code, error messages, or other programming-related artifacts. If you had a detailed error message from RC (maybe in a log file or a debugging mode), that would help. As is, you really should ask on Blender’s stack exchange as there will likely be people who understand Blender better there.

This issue is called Reversed Face Normals. You can flip the normals back in RealityKit using faceCulling instance property. Choose between .front and .none.
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { rvc in
            let tube = try! await Entity(named: "tubeReversed")
            rvc.add(tube)
            print(tube)
            
            var pbr = PhysicallyBasedMaterial()
            pbr.faceCulling = .front
            let cyl = tube.findEntity(named: "cylinder") as! ModelEntity
            cyl.model?.materials[0] = pbr
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .backgroundStyle(.black)
    }
}





